# Creating apex page without default layout in apex 18.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a page without the navigation bar and the top layout in the latest version of apex. Something like the below image

[image]

i'm able to remove the navigation bar, but not able to remove the layer having "help,nobody". I don't want that layer as logo should be the top layer followed by my reports.

how to create a page without the default header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- go to page properties
- scroll down to CSS section
- put the following into the *Inline* CSS:

  ```
  .apex-side-nav .t-Body-actions,
  .apex-side-nav .t-Body-nav,
  .apex-side-nav .t-Body-title {
      top: 0px !important;
  }

  .t-Header-branding {
      height: 0px
  }
  ```

Credits go to Pierre Yotti, http://allipierreapex.blogspot.com/2017/05/how-to-hide-navigation-bar.html

Comment: Works likes a charm :) Thanks to both !